# Finding jekyll link with regex

Tags: regex, jekyll

I couldn't find a `page_url` method or something similar in jekyll, and I don't want my index page to simply list *every* page in my static site. So, I've come up with a solution, but I'm not sure how to implement it: I'll use the default code in the index.html to go through each link and then only list the ones that match a certain regex. Something like this:

```
  <div class="trigger">
    {% for page in site.pages %}
      {% if page.permalink == '^\/.*\/$' %}
      <a class="page-link" href={{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}>{{ page.title }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Only that doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing something simple incorrectly. Can anyone help me? Or point me in the direction of an easier way to link to internal pages without having to know the URL of the page before-hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid condition as {% if page.permalink == 'some string' %} only allows you to compare strings. You cannot use regexp with liquid.

In order to print only needed page you can add a flag in the front matter like :

```
---
[...]
home: true
---
```

And select only pages that contains `page.home == true`

```
<div class="trigger">
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.home and page.home == 'true' %}
    <a class="page-link" href={{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}>{{page.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can also use :

- `split` array filter `{% assign urlArray = page.url | slit: '/' %}`
- `contains` array/string filter `{% if page.url contains 'anyWord' %}do something{% endif %}`

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. I had it set up like that initially, but realized that if I changed a permalink the page would still show up on the index